# django ssl login redirects to non-ssl page

Tags: python, django, ssl

I'm using django with nginx as the webserver. I've got ssl working.

I'm using django's `login` and `logout` from `django.contrib.auth.views` to handle the login.

The problem is that when I login (the login page is https), it doesnt direct to the ssl page.

I've got something like the following in the template.

```
<input type="hidden" name="next"
 value="{% if next %}{{ next|escape }}{% else %}{% url app.views.main %}{% endif %}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out what I can do to make it work

```
<input type="hidden" name="next"
 value="https://{{ request.get_host }}{% if next %}{{ next|escape }}{% else %}{% url app.views.main %}{% endif %}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your nginx web server for example:

```
server {
server_name example.com;
location /admin {
    # force admin to use https
    rewrite (.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

...
}